# Is it possible to establish mTLS using proxy server

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy

I have a pair of public/private certificates, which are very important and can not be stored on my computer, but only in secure premises.

I need to use such certificates to send requests to multiple providers (in my case those are banks).

What I want to do is set up a proxy server which would hold such certificates.
Then I would be able to send requests through that proxy and it will establish mTLS connection with banks using those certificates.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. Do I understand correctly that such approach could be called "reverse termintaion proxy"?
3. Ideally, I would like to do that using nginx. It is possible?

I've found some info in the nginx [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/), but not sure whether it is what I am looking for

Comment: yes, https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/